# Session info lost on BlackBerry (ColdFusion app)

Tags: blackberry, coldfusion, jquery-mobile

This is a ColdFusion/mobile question.  I have a simple web app with a login page. 
 User types their login info, session info is assigned, and they're taken to a 
projects page.  This works fine, but when I try to setup an auto-login (user 
clicks a bookmark on their home screen that passes a username and password), the 
same process should occur, but the session info is lost once they are taken to 
the projects page.  This occurs on the BlackBerry 9370 (w/ touch screen.  not 
sure of the model type), but works fine when testing it in a browser and the 
BlackBerry simulator.   Here's some code for the auto login:

```
<cfquery name="qryAccount">
    EXEC m_AccountLogin
            @Username = <cfqueryparam value="#LCase(url.u)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
            @Password = <cfqueryparam value="#LCase(url.p)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">;
</cfquery>

<cfif qryAccount.recordcount>
    <cflock name="lockAccount" type="exclusive" timeout="10">
        <cfset session.account = {
                isLoggedIn = true,
                MemberID   = qryAccount.iMemberID,
                Role       = qryAccount.iRole }>
    </cflock>

   <cflocation url="/mobile/home/projects.cfm" addtoken="true">
<cfelse>
    <cflocation url="/mobile/index.cfm" addtoken="true">
</cfif>
```

I read that using `<cflocation>` right after assigning session vars may cause 
an issue, so I tried a JavaScript re-direct and still came up short.  Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you would manually append the tokens to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but think this may be a bug in the BB browser, which is pretty lame to begin with (IMO it makes IE6 look usable).

For the sake of testing, is it practical to remove the cflocation to the projects page and put a clickable link there instead?  I'd just like to see if it works that way.  If it does, then for some reason, cflocation is causing the session to be lost.  That shouldn't be the case since you're on CF9, but it'd be nice to prove one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

After CF7, Adobe fixed the issue of setting session variables in the same request as a `<cflocation>` tag. This is no longer an issue.

The likely cause for your session dropping out is that BlackBerry is clearing out your session cookies (cfid,cftoken or jsessionid) when it launches the browser from a home screen bookmark. I have seen this same behaviour in the iPhone as well, it's possible that BB is also doing it.

To confirm (or deny) that this is the case, set up a simple page that outputs:

```
<cfdump var="#session#">
<cfdump var="#getHttpRequestData()#">
```

Navigate to this page on your BB the "normal" way by keying in the URL manually. The first time that the page loads, it will create a session (and send back the associated session cookie(s)). Reload the page and you will see in the http request data dump, a header called cookie(`request.headers.cookie`). This will contain the same session information that you see in the session dump above it.

Now, use the home screen bookmark to load up the page. If BB is in fact clearing out your sessions cookies, then the `request.headers.cookie` will not be there and new session identifiers will be given.

Comment: Would this also apply to Android and iPhone devices?

Comment: @Joshua, we have seen this behaviour on iPhones when launching from the home screen. I have not tested on Android.

Comment: Didn't have a problem on iPhone or Android.  Also didn't have a problem on a later version of the BlackBerry OS.  I believe it was 7, but anything below had issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried using CFHEADER tags to redirect instead of cflocation? Example:

```
<CFHEADER STATUSCODE="302" STATUSTEXT="Object Temporarily Moved">
<CFHEADER NAME="location" VALUE="/mobile/home/projects.cfm">
```

You need both of those tags in order for the redirect to work. I suggest also adding a CFABORT at the end to mimic the way that CFLOCATION also stops current page execution.